# Набор букв и цифр  >  .replace(удаление букв)  >  Вычисление среднего арифметического > Запись

Tags: html, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/x7kLof3n/2/

В голубой ячейке не должно быть ни 'NaN', ни 'Infinity', ни пустоты, а должно быть '3.50', так как стоят числа '3 4 н'. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Я ничего не понимаю, уже второй день сижу за компом и голову ломаю, но до сих пор не знаю, в чём проблема. Я, конечно, пробовал менять некоторые переменные, например, в строке Javascript, где написано 'ПРОБЛЕМА В ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ', и в других переменных тоже пробовал менять значения, но это не помогло...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не буду комментировать сам код и его качество, просто приведу рабочий вариант:

```
setInterval(function mid() {
        var trA = document.getElementById("1.marks");
        var spAA = trA.getElementsByTagName("span");
        var t = 0, count = 0;
        var spA;

        for ( var s = 0; s < spAA.length; s++ ) {
            spA = spAA[s].textContent.replace(/[н\-]/g, "");

            var n = parseInt(spA, 10);

            if(!isNaN(n)) {
                count ++;
                t += n;
            }
        }

        if ( t == 0 ) {
            document.getElementById("1.b").innerText = "-";
        }
        else {
            if(count == 0) {
                return;
            }

            var midA = t / count;

            /* ===ПРОБЛЕМА В ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ=== */
            var numA = Number((midA).toFixed(2));
            if ( numA > 0 ) {
                document.getElementById("1.b").innerText = numA.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Прежде чем производить арифметические операции с числами, которые получают неизвестно откуда, целесообразно проводить проверку isNAN. А при делении - проверку на ноль.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Вы мне очень помогли.